# What are examples of performance degredation which *don't* get posted on trust.salesforce.com?

Tags: support, custom-index, trust

My org had a temporary performance degredation with regards to a custom index on a particular field in a custom object 2 months ago. This was confirmed in writing by Salesforce Support in the ticket that I raised with them. The impact was that some logic which used to always work stopped working.

However, this wasn't ever published on [trust.salesforce.com](https://status.salesforce.com/products/Salesforce_Services?locale=en-US). I have followed up several times with no avail to our Salesforce account manager.

To my knowledge, *all* examples of performance degredation are supposed to be published on trust.salesforce.com but in this example, that hasn't happened here.

Is there a known list of performance degredations that won't get published on trust.salesforce.com? If so, that would be helpful because then developers would have a higher confidence if the issue is with them or with Salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce Trust is primarily for documenting instance-wide disruptions, as noted in the various status indicators in [Use the Salesforce Trust site](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387502&type=1).

> Green (Available): This instance is available and fully functional.
>
> Blue (Informational): Information about the instance that is not a performance issue or service disruption.
>
> Purple (Maintenance): This instance is currently in maintenance. A message will be provided regarding your ability to access the instance during the maintenance.
>
> Yellow (Service Degradation): The instance is still accessible, however there is particular functionality that may be unavailable, or the service may be running with significant latency.
>
> Red (Service Disruption): The instance is inaccessible to customers.

However, they also note that:

> If you are experiencing an issue with the core Salesforce service that has exceeded 10 minutes, and it is not appearing on this site, please open a case via the Help and Training Portal.

If you're experiencing weird behavior, you should always report it to Technical Support. When a certain number of complaints are received, the issue will be reported on trust. I don't believe the threshold is public knowledge, and I wouldn't even know who to ask about it, but I would advise simply this: if you notice odd behavior, don't spend too much time trying to triage it yourself. Technical Support is there to help, and they usually do a fairly good job of it.